# How to connect a 3 phase motor to class-d audio amplifiers

Tags: amplifier, brushless-dc-motor, mosfet-driver

How can I wire this motor to these amplifiers?

I am using 1 1/2 of these stereo amplifiers (3 mono amplifiers) to drive a 3 phase motor. The problem I have is that the amplifier has H-bridge outputs. The usual 3 phase motor drivers are simple push pull, 2 MOSFETs/phase.

There reason that I am not using a standard 3 phase motor driver board, is because I am generating my own 3 phase sine wave pattern.

It is for a musical tone wheel project. I already have a PCB that coverts MIDI note to 3 phase. I just need to amplify the sine waves to drive the motor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to provide a schematic diagram for the amplifier. (This should be obvious.)

Comment: You'll need a motor with 6 wires to do this using full H bridges.

Comment: Depending on what type of modulation the amp uses, you may be able to operate its outputs 'single-ended'. So which IC does your board have (eg. TDA7498, TPA3116) and what modulation is it using?

Comment: @Transistor I don't have a schematic, I would need to sketch one out from the PCB, difficult as it is double sided with big components obscuring the view of the tracks.

Comment: @Andyaka Is there a way I can do this using a BLDC motor driver? Could I hack in to it so that I disconnect it's own 3 phase signal, and input my own external 3 phase signal. Using something like this http://electromen.com/en/products/item/motor-controllers/brushless-dc-motor/http://electromen.com/en/products/item/motor-controllers/brushless-dc-motor/EM-240EM-240

Comment: @BruceAbbott  It is a TDA7498

Comment: The link does not work. I see what your trying to do. You need a source of signals synchronized to produce the 3 phases required. This may only work if the outputs are directly driven by the amps and not capacitivley coupled by a cap.. note all ground/0V rails need to be tied together and the outputs are relative to that ground/0V(this includes the 0V/-ve terminal of the output)  (some output amps drive the outputs deferentially and I don't think that will work in this situation)

Comment: The motor your showing needs a delta drive, either 3 half H-bridges or use a WYE to DELTA HF transformer. Or buy a motor with 6 wires, 2 per phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:-

1. Convert the push-pull outputs to single-ended using audio transformers. This requires 3 relative bulky transformers that might not be easy to source.
2. Split the motor's Delta connection into 3 independent windings. Each winding can then be connected to both output terminals of an amplifier channel. If your motor has its winding wires brought directly out to the plugs then this is relatively easy to do. Simply unsolder the plugs and separate the wire strands. Then use an ohmmeter or continuity tester to find which phase the other end of each strand goes to (there may be several strands per winding). Install 6 plugs and you're done!

[image]

3. Connect each motor phase to *one* output terminal of each amplifier channel (leaving the other terminal disconnected). This should work with class D amps such as the TDA7489, which produce differential PWM (both terminals produce a similar PWM waveform, but one is the antiphase of the other). What you are then doing is using one side of the amp's bridge output.

Whatever method you use, you still have the problem of getting the rotor to stay in sync with the driving frequency. If the motor is lightly loaded and you change frequency *slowly* then the rotor may be able to keep up. Otherwise you need some way to detect the rotor position (eg. Hall sensors) and adjust the frequency and phase to match it. Remember that a BLDC motor is synchronous, so it will not run with the rotor slipping behind like an induction motor does.

Comment: Thank you. I did try option 3. It works, but the motor has very low torque. You are right, if it gets some loading, it loses synchronisation and just vibrates instead of rotating. I realise now that I need a proper closed loops controller. I will give this a try http://vedder.se/tag/bldc/ it is an open source BLDC controller.